# Rename referral in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a way that I can change the referral name in `.Htaccess`?

For example if the referral is `http://Stumbleupon.com` can I change it to `http://Wordpress.com` ??

I don't want to redirect, only change the referral name. I just want to test something with Google Analytics.

There must be a way to catch the referral and rename it. I already saw that somewhere, but I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `edit` syntax for the [`RequestHeader`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader) directive:

```
RequestHeader edit Referer stumbleupon\.com wordpress.com
```

Comment: I added this line to my htaccess. referral stil stumbleupon